# How to post data for iframe src

Tags: html, ajax, post, iframe, get

I have a function like below:

```
function downloadVDRDocument(jsonData) {

var url = "downloadWorkersVDRData.do?visaMasterId="
        + encodeURIComponent(visaMasterId) + "&passpota="
        + encodeURIComponent(jsonData);

$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : url,
    processData : false,
    contentType : false,
    async : false,
    cache : false,
    success : function(response) {
        var elemIF = document.createElement("iframe");
        elemIF.src = url;
        elemIF.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(elemIF);
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        displayOverLay("failure",
                "System error occured, please try after some time.");
    }
});
}
```

It is working fine for me but here method type is:`'GET'` please tell me how to do this in `'POST`' type?

If i put 'POST' type then my ajax is fine but after success response my element elemIF.src = url is using GET call only, Please tell me how to over ride this

I need help, Thank you

Comment: I'm confused by your question... it's basically that easy to change the type to POST, but are you having issues once you have changed it? If that's the case, update the question with information about error messages when you change it...

Comment: I updated my question, Please take a look